# Maintain and re-use existing webdriver browser instance - java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, remotewebdriver

Basically every time I run my java code from eclipse, webdriver launches a new ie browser and executes my tests successfully for the most part. However, I have a lot of tests to run, and it's a pain that webdriver starts up a new browser session every time. I need a way to re-use a previously opened browser; so webdriver would open ie the first time, then the second time, i run my eclipse program, I want it to simply pick up the previous browser instance and continue to run my tests on that same instance. That way, I am NOT starting up a new browser session every time I run my program. 
Say you have 100 tests to run in eclipse, you hit that run button and they all run, then at about the 87th test you get an error. You then go back to eclipse, fix that error, but then you have to re-run all 100 test again from scratch. 
It would be nice to fix the error on that 87th test and then resume the execution from that 87th test as opposed to re-executing all tests from scratch, i.e from test 0 all the way to 100. 
Hopefully, I am clear enough to get some help from you guys, thanks btw. 

Here's my attempt below at trying to maintain and re-use a webdriver internet explorer browser instance:

```
public class demo extends RemoteWebDriver { 

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public Selenium selenium;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
    public String propertyFile;
    String getSessionId;


    public demo() { // constructor


        DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities
                .internetExplorer();
        ieCapabilities
                .setCapability(
                        InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                        true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);


        this.saveSessionIdToSomeStorage(getSessionId);
        this.startSession(ieCapabilities);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Override
      protected void startSession(Capabilities desiredCapabilities) {
        String sid = getPreviousSessionIdFromSomeStorage();
        if (sid != null) {
          setSessionId(sid);
          try {
            getCurrentUrl();
          } catch (WebDriverException e) {
            // session is not valid
            sid = null;
          }
        }
        if (sid == null) {
          super.startSession(desiredCapabilities);
          saveSessionIdToSomeStorage(getSessionId().toString());
        }
      }

    private void saveSessionIdToSomeStorage(String session) {
        session=((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId().toString();
    }

    private String getPreviousSessionIdFromSomeStorage() {
        return getSessionId;
    }
}
```

My hope here was that by overriding the startSession() method from remoteWebdriver, it would somehow check that I already had an instance of webdriver browser opened in i.e and it would instead use that instance as opposed to re-creating a new instance everytime I hit that "run" button in eclipse. 
I can also see that because I am creating a "new driver instance" from my constructor, since constructor always execute first, it creates that new driver instance automatically, so I might need to alter that somehow, but don't know how.

I am a newbie on both stackoverflow and with selenium webdriver and hope someone here can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question:

No. You can't use a browser that is currently running on your computer.  You can use the same browser for the different tests, however, as long as it is on the same execution.

However, it sounds like your real problem is running 100 tests over and over again.  I would recommend using a testing framework (like TestNG or JUnit).  With these, you can specify which tests you want to run (TestNG will generate an XML file of all of the tests that fail, so when you run it, it will only execute the failed tests).

Comment: Thanks for your reply MrTi, so would you recommend TestNg or Junit? The place I work at, I hear them talk about jUnit. If I end up going with jUnit, when I run ONLY the failed tests, would they launch a new browser everytime or simply execute that test using previously launched browser ?

Comment: The way to use the same browser for each test is to start the driver in a `@BeforeClass` method, instead of starting it separately for each test. Both JUnit and TestNG support that - as well as lots of other features to make your testing more efficient.

Comment: @vincebowdren and MrTi, very useful information; I will give it a try, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can re-use the same session again..

In node client you can use following code to attach to existing selenium session

```
var browser = wd.remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub');
browser.attach('df606fdd-f4b7-4651-aaba-fe37a39c86e3', function(err, capabilities) {
  // The 'capabilities' object as returned by sessionCapabilities
  if (err) { /* that session doesn't exist */ }
  else {
    browser.elementByCss("button.groovy-button", function(err, el) {
      ...
    });
  }
});
...
browser.detach();
```

To get selenium session id,

```
driver.getSessionId();
```

Note:
This is available in Node Client only..
To do the same thing in JAVA or C#, you have to override execute method of selenium to capture the sessionId and save it in local file and read it again to attach with existing selenium session

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below steps to use the same browser instance and it worked for me:

If you are having generic or Class 1 in different package the below code snippet will work -

```
package zgenerics;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```

// Class 1 :

```
public class Generics  {

public Generics(){}

protected WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest

public void maxmen() throws InterruptedException, IOException{ 
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    String appURL= "url";
    driver.get(appURL);
    String expectedTitle = "Title";
    String actualTitle= driver.getTitle();
    if(actualTitle.equals(expectedTitle)){
        System.out.println("Verification passed");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Verification failed");
    } }
```

// Class 2 :

```
package automationScripts;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import zgenerics.Generics;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
public class Login extends Generics {
@Test
public void Login() throws InterruptedException, Exception {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,25);

   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("")));
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("")).sendKeys("");

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).sendKeys("");

}
}
```

If your Generics class is in the same package you just need to make below change in your code:

```
public class Generics  {

public Generics(){}

WebDriver driver; }
```

Just remove the protected word from Webdriver code line. Rest code of class 1 remain as it is.

Regards,
Mohit Baluja

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it by extension of classes(Java Inheritance) and creating an xml file. I hope below examples will help:

Class 1 :

```
 package zgenerics;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class SetUp  {

public Generics(){}
protected WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public void maxmen() throws InterruptedException, IOException{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    String appURL= "URL";

    driver.get(appURL);

    String expectedTitle = "Title";

    String actualTitle= driver.getTitle();

    if(actualTitle.equals(expectedTitle)){
        System.out.println("Verification passed");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Verification failed");
    } }
```

Class 2 :

```
 package automationScripts;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import zgenerics.SetUp

 public class Conditions extends SetUp {

@Test
public void visible() throws InterruptedException{

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    boolean signINbutton=driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).isEnabled();
    System.out.println(signINbutton);

    boolean SIGNTEXT=driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println(SIGNTEXT);

    if (signINbutton==true && SIGNTEXT==true){
        System.out.println("Text and button is present");
           }
    else{
        System.out.println("Nothing is visible");
        }
       }
       }
```

Class 3:

```
    package automationScripts;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Footer extends Conditions {

  @Test
  public void footerNew () throws InterruptedException{

    WebElement aboutUs = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("CssSelector"));
    aboutUs.click();


    WebElement cancel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
    cancel.click();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    WebElement TermsNCond = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
    TermsNCond.click();
    }   
    }
```

Now Create an xml file with below code for example and run the testng.xml as testng suite:
copy and paste below code and edit it accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite" parallel="classes" thread-count="3">
<test name="PackTest">
<classes>
   <class name="automationScripts.Footer"/>
</classes>
```

This will run above three classes. That means one browser and different tests.
We can set the execution sequence by setting the class names in alphabetical order as i have done in above classes.