# How does login in selenium web driver work

Tags: selenium, authentication, automated-tests

I have a suite of three test cases to be run in selenium webdriver.
First and third test case requires a login whereas the second does not.
When I run the suite,it asks for the username and password,performs the first test case and then second test case runs in which the login is not required.It is actually a pre login test.After this when the third login starts it doesnt ask me to login again(the second test case should have ideally logged it out)..it instead takes the login credentials I provided in the start.
How is this happening?

Comment: if you have not logged out and the session has not timed out, there should be no reason for your application to ask for login credentials. You should ideally be logging out after each test so all tests are independent of each other.

Comment: @Grasshopper : I understood it now. Thanks :)

Comment: @Grasshopper : Can you please post your comment as answer..so that it could help others in future?

Comment: accepted as answer..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have not logged out and the session has not timed out, there should be no reason for your application to ask for login credentials. You should ideally be logging out after each test so all tests are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below link to achieve this

[Maintain and re-use existing webdriver browser instance - java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212389/maintain-and-re-use-existing-webdriver-browser-instance-java)

Or if you are using TestNG you can use ITestContext where you put the driver in context which you can use in 3rd test case so that you will get the session.