# Using sessions to login in selenium webdriver

Tags: session, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have three test cases to be executed using selenium webdriver in **python** all of which require log in. I have written a login function for this.
But the first test case logs out the user from the application.So now the second testcase should call that login method to log in.After the second test case since the user is not logged out,the third testcase should not call the login method.It should read the login details from the session.
How do I achieve this functionality? Is there a way to check session for username and then accordingly call the login function?

Comment: You can use the below link to get your result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212389/maintain-and-re-use-existing-webdriver-browser-instance-java

Comment: or you can use ITestContext if using testNG and pass the driver to your third test case instead of creating new driver in third test case

Comment: @MonisMajeed : I am creating driver in every test case coz I dont really have control over that part of the code..Can I do something like this : In my login method,save the session details after it has logged in. Now in every test case check that session value.If set to null log in else dont..?

Comment: yes you can do that.

Comment: But there is a problem with this approach. I am trying to save the session using pickle like this `pickle.dump(config.driver.get_cookies() , open("QuoraCookies.pkl","wb"))
  for cookie in pickle.load(open("QuoraCookies.pkl", "rb")):
   print(cookie)` . Is this correct?

Comment: Is there some other way to save it? I just want to access the username from the session

Comment: you can have a contol over driver, you can pass the same driver to third test case instead of creating the driver again in third test case